# Garbage in TCP message - C++/Java communication

Tags: java, c++, sockets, tcp, send

I'm having a slight problem in my C++ client - Java server application.
Sockets successfully connect, and transmit several messages, but then comes this part:

```
msgBuilder<<"TASK?\n";
mymsg = msgBuilder.str();
send(tcp_sock,mymsg.c_str(),8,0);
msgBuilder.str("");
msgBuilder.clear();
```

The java side reads

```
msg = in.readLine();
while(!(msg.equals("TASK?"))){
System.out.println("Got "+msg+" expected TASK?");
msg = in.readLine();
}
```

Problem is, it reads two of what I assume are null characters which I cannot paste here, for some reason.
I can get over it by switching to "contains" I guess, but I am interested in what's causing this?

Comment: Well `send` is transmitting 8 bytes and the msg is 6 bytes so you will get 2 bytes of junk that was in the buffer after the newline.  You want to send mymsg.length().

Comment: Oh the hazards of copy-pasting code! Thanks man, it was the previous call of send that actually left junk in the buffer. Problem solved!

Comment: You also need to check `msg` for `null` before you do anything else with it.

Comment: Additionally, that looks like C++ not C

Comment: @ChrisStratton Also true, will change it

Answer (score 3):

```
send(tcp_sock,mymsg.c_str(),8,0);
```

should be

```
send(tcp_sock,mymsg.c_str(),mymsg.length(),0); // or size() or whatever it is. Not 8.
```